# Некорректно работает parse_dates в pd.read_excel()

Tags: python, pandas, excel, dataframe

Открываю Excel файл следующим образом:

```
with gzip.open('new.xlsx.gz') as a:   
    excel_file = pd.read_excel(a, sheet_name = 'Sheet', skiprows=range(0,2), parse_dates=["Unnamed: 0"])
excel_dates = pd.to_datetime(excel_file["Unnamed: 0"],errors="coerce").dt.floor("D").unique()
print(excel_dates)
print(excel_file.head(10))
print(excel_file.info())
```

Результат `print(excel_dates)`:

```
    ['2020-11-14T00:00:00.000000000']
# и это все, строчек должно быть 100K +
```

Ожидаемый результат такой:

```
 2020-11-14   
 2020-11-14   
 2020-11-14
```

Результат `print(excel_file.head(10))`:

```
 Unnamed: 0            
0 2020-11-14 00:00:00  
1 2020-11-14 00:00:00  
2 2020-11-14 00:00:00
```

Результат `print(excel_file.info())`:

```
0   Unnamed: 0                      234374 non-null  datetime64[ns]
```

Как правильно парсить даты? Их нужно сравнивать на совпадение с такими датами:

```
 2020-08-09
 2020-08-15
 2020-10-25
 2020-08-29
 2020-10-11
```

---

[Вот фрагмент данных](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Yea2DyTz9ChD1nS2y1gYwojfOBiJx55JEq7476dtG5g/edit?usp=sharing), который скопирован c реальных данных.

*Дополнение:* При таком коде:

```
with gzip.open('new.xlsx.gz') as a:
            excel_file = pd.read_excel(a, sheet_name = 'Sheet', skiprows=[0,2], parse_dates=[0])
            excel_dates = pd.to_datetime(excel_file["Название столбца"],errors="coerce").dt.floor("D").unique()
```

И когда хочу напечатать `print(excel_dates.info())`:

Выходит ошибка:

```
print(excel_dates.info())
AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'info'
```

Comment: Можете выложить new.xlsx.gz на какой-нибудь файлообменник (если он не содержит конфиденциальной информации)?

Comment: простите не могу, он конфиденциальный и там 35 mb

Comment: @MaxU я через head и tail просмотрела, вроде бы ошибок нет. Вы сможете подсказать, как решить проблему без файла?

Comment: Врядли я смогу помочь без небольшого (3-5 строк), но __воспроизводимого__ примера данных

Comment: @MaxU rкогда хочу напечатать excel_dates.info, мне выдает ошибку 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'info' , хотя этого не должно быть

Comment: объект `excel_dates` - это `numpy.ndarray` и у него нет метода `.info()`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Судя по примеру данных, строки с индексами `0` и `2` нужно пропустить:

```
df = pd.read_excel("/path/to/test.xlsx", skiprows=[0,2], parse_dates=[0])
```

результат:

```
In [165]: df
Out[165]: 
  Period start time    Name_2    Name_3  Name_4  Name_5  Name_6  Name_7  Name_8  Name_9  Name_10  Name_11  Name_12  ...  Name_21  Name_22  Name_23  Name_24  Name_25  Name_26  Name_27  Name_28  Name_29  Name_30  Name_31  Name_32
0        2020-11-14  dgdt68bg  edrt5464  rte544    0.64    0.65    0.46    0.49    0.57     0.96     0.20     0.92  ...     0.15     0.94     0.53     0.13     0.80     0.57     0.56     0.36     0.35     0.30     0.69     0.13
1        2020-11-14   sfsfe35     ew454  st43wt    0.24    0.48    0.37    0.05    0.87     0.94     0.28     0.41  ...     0.91     0.28     0.50     0.46     0.11     0.68     0.01     0.46     0.03     0.74     0.29     0.34
2        2020-11-14  sget4454  35353wfe  et3453    0.33    0.67    0.04    0.25    0.57     0.54     0.75     0.84  ...     0.07     0.19     0.05     0.61     0.62     0.27     0.99     0.15     0.10     0.48     0.25     0.01

[3 rows x 32 columns]

In [166]: df.info()
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 3 entries, 0 to 2
Data columns (total 32 columns):
 #   Column             Non-Null Count  Dtype         
---  ------             --------------  -----         
 0   Period start time  3 non-null      datetime64[ns]
 1   Name_2             3 non-null      object        
 2   Name_3             3 non-null      object        
 3   Name_4             3 non-null      object        
 4   Name_5             3 non-null      float64       
 5   Name_6             3 non-null      float64       
 6   Name_7             3 non-null      float64       
 7   Name_8             3 non-null      float64       
 8   Name_9             3 non-null      float64       
 9   Name_10            3 non-null      float64       
 10  Name_11            3 non-null      float64       
 11  Name_12            3 non-null      float64       
 12  Name_13            3 non-null      float64       
 13  Name_14            3 non-null      float64       
 14  Name_15            3 non-null      float64       
 15  Name_16            3 non-null      float64       
 16  Name_17            3 non-null      float64       
 17  Name_18            3 non-null      float64       
 18  Name_19            3 non-null      float64       
 19  Name_20            3 non-null      float64       
 20  Name_21            3 non-null      float64       
 21  Name_22            3 non-null      float64       
 22  Name_23            3 non-null      float64       
 23  Name_24            3 non-null      float64       
 24  Name_25            3 non-null      float64       
 25  Name_26            3 non-null      float64       
 26  Name_27            3 non-null      float64       
 27  Name_28            3 non-null      float64       
 28  Name_29            3 non-null      float64       
 29  Name_30            3 non-null      float64       
 30  Name_31            3 non-null      float64       
 31  Name_32            3 non-null      float64       
dtypes: datetime64[ns](1), float64(28), object(3)
memory usage: 896.0+ bytes
```

Comment: excel_dates = pd.to_datetime(excel_file["Unnamed: 0"],errors="coerce").dt.floor("D").unique(), а вы можете пожалуйста еще подсказать, как работать с этой строчкой, так как мне нужно превратить список дат в отдельный датафрейм, и на данном этапе у меня ошибка, с тем, чтобы открыть файл у меня в принципе проблем не было

Comment: @MRO, повторюсь - для того, чтобы помочь нужен __воспроизводимый__ пример данных и полная информация об ошибке ;) PS "воспроизводимый" - это тот, который позволит воспроизвести проблему

Answer (score 6):

Если исходить из дополнительной информации, полученной из комментариев, основная проблема в том как преобразовать Numpy вектор в Pandas.Series:

```
excel_dates = pd.to_datetime(excel_file["Unnamed: 0"],errors="coerce").dt.floor("D").unique()
excel_dates = pd.Series(excel_dates)
```

Comment: С инфо это не основная проблема, так как при вызове print(excel_dates) выходит  не  2020-11-14, а ['2020-11-14T00:00:00.000000000']. Это было основной проблемой, инфо это было как-бы добавочное действие, чтобы разобраться в ошибке

Comment: @MRO, решение, предложенное в этом ответе не помогло??

Comment: Прошу прощения, кажется помогло, сейчас я еще раз прогоню уже весь код.